# Substring ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text

Tags: postgresql, psql

```
SELECT substring(category FROM '[0-9]+') from microwaves;
```

This works fine and returns the microwave categories that are numeric.

```
UPDATE microwaves SET category = '' WHERE substring(category FROM '[0-9]+');
```

This throws an error in Postgres 9.5

> ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text

How can I update the numeric fields?

Answer (score 1):

The WHERE clause is used to filter the results to all items that make the clause true, but SUBSTRING() returns text.  You're probably looking for one of the following:

```
UPDATE microwaves SET category = '' WHERE substring(category FROM '[0-9]+') is null;
```

-or-

```
UPDATE microwaves SET category = '' WHERE substring(category FROM '[0-9]+') is not null;
```

Comment: Even simpler: `WHERE category ~ '[0-9]+'`